# What should the width of the border be?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You have made a rectangular stained glass window that is
$2$ feet by $4$ feet. You have 7 square feet of clear glass to create
a border of uniform width around the window. What should
the width of the border be?

Comment: Question is not clear. $2$ feet of stained glass seems to be missing a dimension. And you've got $7$ square feet of clear glass, but with no form? No given form would allow adopting to any width $x$ that might be needed; there is no such thing as $7$ square feet of _liquid_ glass.

Comment: Here is solved page 3 and with a better wording: http://www.classzone.com/eservices/home/pdf/teacher/LA205BAD.pdf edited according with the pdf (which makes sense with the picture you uploaded)

Comment: *You have a rectangular stained glass window that is
$2$ feet by $4$ feet. You have to create totally 7 square feet of clear glass including a border of uniform width around the window. What should the width of the border be?*... I would edit it so had I seen it earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total area of the window, including the border and the stained glass, is the product of the height and width: $h \cdot w = (4 + 2x)(2 + 2x) = 4x^2 + 12x + 8\ \text{ft}^2$. The area of the stained glass is $2 \cdot 4 = 8\ \text{ft}^2$, so the area of the border is
$4x^2 + 12x + 8 - 8\ \text{ft}^2$, which is given to be $7\ \text{ft}^2$. Thus 
$$4x^2 + 12x - 7 = 0 \\
\implies 4x^2 -2x + 14x - 7 = 0 \\
\implies 2x(2x - 1) + 7(2x - 1) = 0 \\
\implies (2x - 1)(2x + 7) = 0 \\
\implies x = \frac{1}{2}, \frac{-7}{2}
$$

Obviously, the width of the border can't be negative, so $x = \frac{1}{2}\ \text{ft}^2$.